# Print 2 names in Google Charts Bar

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to make sure that in the diagram each line has its own name, as indicated in the second picture.

What I did:

[image: Image 1]

What I want:

[image: image 2]

I tried to put an array instead of a string in the title.
I tried to put each element individually a value name, but it did not work out as it should.

Tried to do so, but did as needed.

```
        vehicleOperationData: [
            ['Range','Value'],
            ['Today', 1000],
            ['Yesterday', 1170],
            ['',0]
        ],

        chartOptions: {
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            chart: {
                subtitle: 'Sales and Expenses'
            }
        }
```

I tried to use an array in the name, it threw an error

```
            vehicleOperationData: [
            ['Range','Current','Previous'],
            [['Today','Yesterday'], 1000, 1170],
        ]
```

As a result, I did not find what I wanted and tried to find answers in googlecharts documentation, but I did not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in google charts, to truly have "groups" of bars, each with a different color,
you need to use separate columns, or series...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Range', 'Series 0', 'Series 1'],
  ['Today', 1000, 1170],
]);
```

however, in the example above, you will notice there is only one row,
so no yesterday.

in order to reproduce the desired chart,
you will first need to use a style role, in order to color each bar separately.

you will also need to insert blank rows in order to make the "groups"...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Range', 'Value', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}],
  ['Today', 1000, '#3366cc'],
  ['Yesterday', 1170, '#dc3912'],
  ['', null, null],
  ['this week', 7000, '#3366cc'],
  ['last week', 9170, '#dc3912'],
]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Range', 'Value', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}],
    ['Today', 1000, '#3366cc'],
    ['Yesterday', 1170, '#dc3912'],
    ['', null, null],
    ['this week', 7000, '#3366cc'],
    ['last week', 9170, '#dc3912'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    title: 'Vehicle Operating Rate'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```